# Cannot assign databases to 2 different users

Tags: php, phalcon

So I'm using hostinger as my webhost as they supprt phalcon framework, But the way my site was developed it doesn't support the user of 2 users for 2 different databases, its use to 1 use per 2 databases, What can i do about this?

````
define("GLOBAL_DB", "db1");
define("FORUMS_DB", "db2");

/**
 * Specify all folders to include
 */
$includes = array(
    LIB."/core/*.php",
    LIB."/core/utils/*.php",
    LIB."/core/utils/discord/*.php",
    LIB."/handlers/*.php",
    LIB."/core/template/*.php",
    LIB."/core/client/*.php",
);

/**
 * Build includes
 */
foreach ($includes as $i)
    foreach(glob($i) as $file)
        require_once($file);

/*
 * Set up an sql database instance.
*/
Registry::set ("database", new Database("localhost", "user", "pass", "db" ));
$db = Registry::getDatabase();
$db->connect();```
````

Comment: I'm abit confused, you want both databases to be active for 1 user or depending on the user he uses a certain database?